# How to find all matching classes with Javascript and allow them all to run a function

Tags: javascript

The below will only find the first .available class and run my fuction. I need it to find all .available classes so that all of them can fun the function.

How would I do this?

```
this.DOM = {};
this.DOM.available = this.DOM.product.querySelector('.available');

this.DOM.available.addEventListener('click', () => this.open());
```

Full Code

```
    class Item {
      constructor(el) {
        this.DOM = {};
        this.DOM.el = el;
        this.DOM.product = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.product');
        this.DOM.productBg = this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__bg');
        this.DOM.productImg = this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__img');
        this.DOM.available = this.DOM.product.querySelectorAll('.available');

        this.info = {
          img: this.DOM.productImg.src,
          title: this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__title').innerHTML,
          subtitle: this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__subtitle').innerHTML,
          // description: this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__description').innerHTML,
          price: this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__price').innerHTML
        };

        this.initEvents();
      }
      open() {
        DOM.details.fill(this.info);
        DOM.details.open({
          productBg: this.DOM.productBg,
          productImg: this.DOM.productImg
        });
      }
      initEvents() {
        this.DOM.available.addEventListener('click', () => this.open());
      }

    };
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and forEach instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a collection of all matching elements and then use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop over the collection and assign the event handler:

```
this.DOM = {};
this.DOM.available = this.DOM.product.querySelectorAll('.available');
this.DOM.available.forEach(function(item){  
  item.addEventListener('click', () => item.open());
});
```

Comment: I tried this but got an error. I've added my full code, maybe you can notice the issue?
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>"

Comment: I tried the below, but I still get that same error

`this.DOM.available = [].slice.call(this.DOM.product.querySelectorAll('.available'));`

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon You do not need to convert the collection returned from `.querySelectorAll()` to an array to be able to call `.forEach()` on it. The DOM Collection supports that interface.

Comment: thanks for the response Scott. Yeah not sure what issue is being created after I add the queryselectorAll & the foreach..

Comment: @monsaic123 That is not necessary. You may call `.forEach()` directly on the returned collection from `.querySelectorAll()` as I've shown in my answer. The error you mention indicates that you are trying to call an  `.open` method on a `div` element, but `div` element's don't have an `open` method. This is caused because of the use of the arrow function in the callback. Within an arrow function `this` remains unchanged, so you should use a reference to the element.

Comment: @monsaic123 See my updated comment and answer. Your use of `this` within the callback is the issue.

Comment: Thanks Scott. How would I create a reference to the element while still getting this data in my open() function?
Sorry you don't need to provide me with the code, just looking for a point in the right direction... Still learning DOM, sorry if a stupid question

Comment: Oops! My bad, I have removed my incorrect comment. Turns out I was confusing `querySelectorAll` with `getElementsByClassName`. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @monsaic123 I've updated the answer to show that. Instead of using `this`, use the `.forEach()` looping variable - - in my example, that's `item`.